# Does pyodbc have encoding issues on version 3+?

Tags: python, teradata, pyodbc

... or is it just me? I read version 2 resolved encoding issues -- I figured this is related. I have not had problems on MSSQL servers, just our latest TeraData server.

python==3.4.3
pyodbc==3.0.10

Other posts recommend I try combinations of 'CHARSET=UTF8;ENCODING=UTF8' in my connect(). These are in my DSN but have not made a perceivable difference.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN={TeraData};")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.tables()
rows = cursor.fetchall()

In [28]: rows[0].table_name, rows[0].table_name.encode('utf_16_le')
```

Out[28]: ('扁牯䱴獩却獥楳湯', b'AbortListSession')

Comment: I am using the same drivers with Perl and am able to successfully query the TeraData DB. This has to be python related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyodbc 4.x significantly improved Unicode handling. Version [4.0.7](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/releases/tag/4.0.7) included a specific fix for Teradata. If at all possible you should be using the latest version (currently 4.0.26 at the time of writing this answer).

Also, see [this information in the pyodbc wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode#teradata).